# PHP, Writing to CSV not on same line?

Tags: php, file, csv, fgetcsv, fputcsv

```
function writePlayerInfo($playerFName, $playerSName, $phone, $email){
    $data = array();
    array_push($data, $playerFName, $playerSName, $phone, $email);
    $handleName = fopen("data/names.csv","w");
    foreach ($data as $line)
    {
        fputcsv($handleName,explode(',',$line));
    }
    fclose($handleName);
    $datas = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    writePlayerInfo($fname, $lname, $phone, $email);
    header('Location: createplayer.php');
}
```

Hi guys, thanks in advance

Im trying to write to a csv file, i have got it working, my current code displays information in the csv file like this:

```
Dave 
Smith
01210112345
Email@stack.com
```

However i would like it to write to the file like this

```
Dave Smith 01210112345 Email@stack.com
```

Then i would like it so the next time i call the function it writes on the line below, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fputcsv with delimiter="\t"

```
function writePlayerInfo($playerFName, $playerSName, $phone, $email){
    $data = array();
    array_push($data, $playerFName, $playerSName, $phone, $email);
    $handleName = fopen("data/names.csv","w");
    fputcsv($handleName, $data, "\t");
    fclose($handleName);
    $datas = array();
}
```

Comment: When i now call the function again, it does not write to a new line, simply overrides the current

Comment: @RSDolpp that's because you've opened the file with "w". You'll want "a" instead. Check the fopen manual to see what those settings do ;)

Comment: Your a legend my sir.